# Regex to match blocks of text with key phrases in the middle

Tags: regex, vb.net, text, grouping

VB2010: I have text that consists of blocks of text that start with day and time DD  HHMM and end only at the next day/time.

Here is my sample text:

```
18  2131  Z50000  ZZ-AAA
PR
PR                                                             
AGM TPS P773QQ 1500 DCA  22FEB                                 
21,77,23,M10,F,26,3100,2
OK                                      


18  2134  Z50000  ZZ-AAA
PR
QU HMKKDBB
.DDVZAZC 182134
ARR
FI US1500/AN P773QQ/DA KDCA/AD KMIA/IN 2026/FB 152/LA  /LR  
DT DDL DCAV 182134 M33A
-  OS KMIA /GNO6541/R200RR


18  2134  Z50000  ZZ-AAA
PR
PR
ARR OPN P773QQ 1500 DCA  22FEB
0757
OK                                      


18  2135  Z50000  ZZ-AAA
PR
PR                                                             
ARR M58 P773QQ 1500 DCA  22FEB                                 
212
UNKNOWN POL/SPOL                         
QU HMKKDBB
.DDVZAZC 182134
ARR
FI US1500/AN P773QQ/DA KDCA/AD KMIA/IN 2026/FB 152/LA  /LR  
DT DDL DCAV 182134 M33A
-  OS KMIA /GNO6541/R200RR



18  2136  Z50000  ZZ-AAA
PRF 1500/18 MIA  IN       0152 333

18  2137  Z50000  ZZ-AAA
PR
 PRZ 1500/18 MIA  IN  2026 N/A  333
```

My goal is to get only the blocks of text that have key phrases ^FI and ^DT in the middle. The matching groups should contain only two blocks. The one from 18  2134 and end at M33A and then from 18  2135 to M33A.

I have tried:

This works for the most part except it starts the match at the prior block.

```
RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
^\d\d  \d{4}(.*?)^FI US(.*?)^DT DDL(.*?)\r
```

This one I took from another post but cant seem to wrap my head around. It matches only the first part of every block.

```
RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
^\d\d  \d{4}.*\r[\s\S]*?(?=(?:^\d\d  \d{4}|$))
```

Haven't used regex in a while so any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `^\d\d  \d{4}\b(?:(?!^\d\d  \d{4}|^FI|^DT).)*?^(?:FI|DT).*?(?=^\d\d  \d{4}\b|\Z)` with multiline and singleline options.

Comment: Let me give that a shot.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/PqZsoA/1, there must be a `+` after the space between the day and time. Or use two spaces, as in your example text, https://regex101.com/r/PqZsoA/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?ms)^\d\d +\d{4}\b(?:(?!^(?:\d\d +\d{4}\b|FI|DT)).)*?^(?:FI|DT).*?(?=^\d\d +\d{4}\b|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PqZsoA/3) (Though it is a PCRE regex test, it will work the same in .NET).

**Pattern details**

- `(?ms)` - multiline and singleline options
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d\d +\d{4}\b` - 2 digits, 1 or more spaces and 4 digits as a whole word
- `(?:(?!^(?:\d\d +\d{4}\b|FI|DT)).)*?` - any char, 0+ repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start the sequence: start of a line, 2 digits, 1 or more spaces and 4 digits as a whole word, or `FI` or `DT`
- `^(?:FI|DT)` - `FI` or `DT` at the start of a line
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=^\d\d +\d{4}\b|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires `^\d\d +\d{4}\b` (start of a line, 2 digits, 1 or more spaces and 4 digits as a whole word) or `\Z` (end of string) to match immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: That appears to work! thanks for the help. let me spend some time digesting the construct.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should find what you need, if single line enabled

`[0-3]\d\s+[0-2]\d[0-5]\d.*?(FI.*?)\n(DT.*?)\n`

**Explanation:**

`[0-3]\d\s+[0-2]\d[0-5]\d` day hour and minute check

`.*?` ungreedy capturing, . includes newline

`(FI.*?)\n` first group, FI line, until line break

`(DT.*?)\n` second group, same deal

Comment: In testing this it captures those blocks that do not have the FI and DT. So it starts at the day/time and keeps matching until such time it finds the FI and DT. Those blocks that do not have it are being included. let me see if I can use it as a base.

Comment: In testing this it captures those blocks that do not have the FI and DT. So it starts at the day/time and keeps matching until such time it finds the FI and DT. Those blocks that do not have it are being included.

Comment: @sinDizzy I did say first group and second group, but you might have other needs

Comment: Yes thank you. What I mean is that this regex has the same issue as my first regex. namely that it will match blocks of text starting at the first date/time and then continue until it finds FI and DT. IN that match there is part of the prior block that doesn't have the key phrases.

Comment: What do you think of this ^\d\d  \d{4}(.*?)(?=(^\d\d  \d{4}|\Z)) with single line and multiline enabled?this will get me ALL blocks and then I can post-process the list with code.

Comment: @sinDizzy this doesn't work at all. For one, the two numbers have more than one space between them. On the other hand, it just returns everything

Comment: Once I made it two spaces it works but gives me all blocks. I then post process each block to see if it's the one I need. That's the only way I have seen that works.